# Custom Gallery Thumbnails in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, gallery

Thanks for reading!

I am using the Android Gallery tutorial and wondering if there's a way to customize the thumbnails of the gallery> For eg: Display caption ON the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all approaches suggested here, I wasn't able to still get a custom gallery the way I wanted it to. I kept running into `ClassCastException`. So, here's what worked for me till now. This is **just a workaround and incase someone comes up with a better way to design a custom gallery - do post your answer here so I can accept it.**

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You can completely customize your `Gallery` items. Just return whatever `View` you want from the `getView` method of the `ImageAdapter`.

(I assume your are using [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) tutorial)

Comment: Thanks mgv! (Yes, I am using the same tutorial). I have an ImageView object in getView(). How do I add a caption on the image? AFAIK, I have to create a custom single row and define the layout as having an ImageView and a TextView. Or is there another way?

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://mytelcoit.com/2010/02/programming-android-create-icon-with-text-using-gridview-and-layout-inflater/ It uses a GridView but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks mgv! But, I am looking for adding a textview as a caption inside the image thumbnail.

Comment: Also, how do I customize my gallery? If I write a class that extends Gallery - how do I extend Activity? How will the app even load>?

Comment: Can someone please help me - how can I create a custom Gallery that includes text inside each thumbnail?