# How to add text on a image in gallery view

Tags: android, layout, textview, gallery

I have about 100 channel names(text) and a image gallery. And a button on the top of the screen which will open the list of countries. If user choose any country then i have to load the channel of that country in a gallery.

I want that when user will choose a country from menu then i will just add the channels name to the images in gallery.

That mean gallery will show the images which have channel name written on it.

I want to know that how will i add the text on a image in gallery at run time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement custom adapter for gallery. As you can see from [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) that adapter's [`getView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) method returns View object which can be some custom layout.

See same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517101/custom-gallery-thumbnails-in-android)

See [tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327) for adapter in listview.